# Pass a model value to Jquery function

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, model

I am trying to pass the value of a model to a jquery function (**openBookingSnap**)when a hyperlink is clicked.
But I am unable to get the value passed.
Here is my CSHTML Code. Please tell me what am I missing here?

```
 @model List<Model.Booking> 
 @using (Html.BeginPanel(true))
 {
   <table>
    <tr>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++){
          if (i > 0 && i % 3 == 0)
          {
            @:</tr><tr> 
          }
          <td>
            <div id="dataListItem" style ="width: 90px"><a style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="VslVoy.Ux.openBookingSnap(Model[i].bkgNoUid);">@Html.DisplayFor(m => Model[i].bkgNo)</a></div>
          </td>
        }
     </tr>
 </table>

 }
```

Comment: use `@` and If `bkgNoUid` is string wrap it in quotes i.e. `onclick="VslVoy.Ux.openBookingSnap('@Model[i].bkgNoUid');"`

Comment: You have invalid html because of duplicate `id `attributes. Use `<div class="dataListItem" ...>` instead. The recommended approach is to add `data-val-bkgNoUid="@Model[i].bkgNoUid"` attribute to the `<div>` and use $('.dataListItem').click(function() { var id = $(this).data('bkgNoUid'); ..... });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing `@` before model - try like this

```
onclick="VslVoy.Ux.openBookingSnap(@(Model[i].bkgNoUid));"
```

Hope it works - Happy coding !!

Comment: No problem - Happy coding :)